# Java android hotspot get only connect List of clients

Tags: java, android

I want to get List of clients which are current connect to my hotspot I did this :

```
public List<WifiClient> getClients() {
List<WifiClient> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.clear();

// Basic sanity checks
Pattern macPattern = Pattern.compile("..:..:..:..:..:..");

BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" +");
        if (parts.length < 6) {
            continue;
        }

        String ipAddr = parts[0];
        String hwAddr = parts[3];
        String device = parts[5];

        if (!device.equals(deviceName)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!macPattern.matcher(parts[3]).find()) {
            continue;
        }
        boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddr).isReachable(1000);  // this is network call so we cant do that on UI thread, so i take background thread.
        if (isReachable) {
            result.add(new WifiClient(ipAddr, hwAddr));
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "", e);
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    }
}
return result;
}
```

But I have timeout here :

```
            `boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddr).isReachable(1000);  // this is network call so we cant do that on UI thread, so i take background thread.`
```

When I don't do this I have list of all users which were connected , but no now.

Comment: maybe 1 second is not long enough?

Comment: @ScaryWombat  I change to 5 sec but when I debug I have immediately IOException

Comment: I am failing to see the problem - can you not just wrap the method call with a `try-catch` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes I have a try-catch block

Answer (score 0):

As your `try-catch` is outside your loop, if an exception is caught, the loop will not continue.

try

```
while (...) {
  ...
  try {
    boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddr).isReachable(1000);            
    if (isReachable) {
        result.add(new WifiClient(ipAddr, hwAddr));
    }
  } catch (IOException ee) {//print it?
  }
  ....
 } // end loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need `/proc/net/arp` to get connected clients? It's an ARP table mapping you local net addresses to hardware addresses.

Consider using `/proc/net/tcp` instead - it lists all open TCP sockets. See here http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html